# Foundation Excavation: How much larger than the RCC footing?

Tags: structural-engineering, foundations

I am trying to estimate the volume of excavation needed for the foundations of a structure from the drawings provided.

The drawings clearly give the dimensions of the RC / cement footing but I suppose the actual excavation will need to be larger than this? How much larger should I plan for in the costing calculations.

Any rules of thumb?

Another issue that comes to mind is that although the RC / cement footing structures are rectangular or various dimensions, any practical excavation would have a slight slope in the walls that increases the excavation volume? Or is that not so significant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any code which defines this, but a one meter "working perimeter" around the footing is probably more than enough.

Regarding the slope of the excavation walls, that's trickier to define with a blanket statement. The problem is that the slope is necessary to give the soil stability. Unfortunately, the soil's stability is highly dependent on its properties ([cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(geology)), [angle of repose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_repose), etc), so the requisite angle to stabilize the excavation is also a function of these properties. Therefore, a blanket statement of "a slope of X is adequate" can't be given without knowledge of the type of soil being discussed.

That being said, for non-problematic soils (i.e. non-expansive and non-collapsible soils, with a reasonable SPT, etc), a long-term excavation can usually be given a 2:3 slope (two vertical for three horizontal), so adopting such a slope for a temporary excavation would be very conservative. Depending on the soil, I believe even a 1:1 slope could be possible for a temporary excavation.